# How to handle ListView scroll direction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a dummy list of items
I want to show a floating action button in swip up direction and hide it in down direction.
how can I implement this functionality ?

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool upDirection = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(index.toString()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton:upDirection==true?FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},):Container() ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

All you need is a `NotificationListener.onNotification` callback:

```dart
NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    final ScrollDirection direction = notification.direction;
    return true;
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 100,
    itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('$i')),
  ),
)
```

---

##### Full code:

```dart
bool _visible = true;
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
    body: NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        final ScrollDirection direction = notification.direction;
        setState(() {
          if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            _visible = false;
          } else if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
            _visible = true;
          }
        });
        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('$i')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Great! do we really have to dispose the controller?

Comment: @WesleyBarnes Yes, it's a good practice to do so (I didn't include it though).

Comment: It just needed 
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

Comment: It's interesting how we get `ScrollDirection.forward` when we are going **back** (to the **beginning** of the list) and `ScrollDirection.reverse` when we are going down forward (towards the end of the list).

Comment: @Aleksandar Yes, I also feel that it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Though the above solution answers the question, I think its a bit inefficient since you're calling `setState()` everytime a change in direction happens. This might work in small apps but in big complex apps can lead high time lags as when you call s`etState()` the whole widget tree rebuild itself and its subsequent children.

My solution? Use a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [Consumer](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

```
Provider acts like a reference to a widget and a certain variable of which you want to keep a track of and using consumer you can listen to change when you need and where you need.
```

Benefit over setState(), when the builder method of consumer is called it only rebuilds the widget which listens to it(in your case the bottom app bar) and doesn't affect the rest of the widget tree.

Also Providers are back-bone of flutter state management so I would highly recommend them knowing as soon as possible.

Comment: `NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>` tracks only events of scroll direction change, so for each scroll there is only two events - one when the user starts scrolling (you get the direction from that) and one when the scroll is finished (in which case the direction is `ScrollDirection.idle`.
So, the code from @CopsOnRoad is not inefficient, but it's good to think about efficiency with state updates in general.
Also, you can use `ValueNotifier` with [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using ScrollController we can check up and down scroll using this method in listview, singlechildscrollview, girdview when axis.vertical and when axis.horizontal can check scroll left to right

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
@override
void initState() {
_scrollController.addListener(() {
  if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
      ScrollDirection.forward) {
    update(0.0, true);
  } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
      ScrollDirection.reverse) {
    update(70, false);
  }
});
  super.initState();
}
```